# Expand & collapse in asp.net with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net 2.0 and c#.

I have two divs `<div id="div1">` and `<div id="div2">`, what I want is this that when I click on the link, div1 will collapse and div2 expand and the vice versa. I have to do this in JQuery.

Comment: Have you ever read a jquery tutorial?  This is trivially simple to do, and you might be better served by learning a bit more about the technologies and libraries you plan to utilize.  Reading just about any beginning tutorial on jquery should teach you how to accomplish what you want.

Comment: if the example you have find is not working, maybe is better to try to locate the error. I delete my answer and I will check it out later.

Comment: No, I belive the answer provided by you is correct. I have to check it on my end. I'll update here with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple Google search the first one is and a good one.

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html

Comment: I have checked this already, I have downloaded the files too. but it is not working.

Comment: @Rahul I just add it to my pages and its working very nice. What is your problem - where is not working for you ?

Comment: I have done this thing: <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(".content1").hide(); jQuery(".content2").hide(); //toggle the componenet with class msg_body jQuery(".heading").click(function() { jQuery(".content1").slideToggle(500); jQuery(".content2").slideToggle(500); }); }); </script>

Comment: and this code in the body:
<p class="heading">Header-1 </p> <div class="content1">Div1</div> <br /> <div class="content2">Div2</div>

Comment: It is working fine, but I want that when content1 is displayed contentent2 should be hide. please help